# service fabric communication listeners not calling from stateless application to another stateless service application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cloud-services, service-fabric-stateless

Actually i created service fabric stateless application.While adding instance listener like as follows

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
        }
```

But these listener is not taken for stateless.Its giving error like not have any instance with parameter.either single or 2 parameters.
Because of these reasons i tried with

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> 
      CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
        }
```

->As for with console application(with service proxy) able to call the service method
->But coming with another stateless application i am not able to call any method.And not throwing any exception

Tq.
Please can anyone suggest me in which it will work

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you call the service?

Comment: As from console application and from stateless application in am calling like as follows
            var adder = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommonInterfacePkg.ICommunication>(new Uri("fabric:/FieldDataCaptureApp/FieldDataCaptureApi"));
            var result = await adder.OnRouteMessageaAsync("sadsadasd");
In the case from service also same way i am calling like same way as above please suggest me how can i call from stateless to stateless

Comment: Can you verify that you have an endpoint like this `<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />` in your service manifest?